# Variable class array

Tags: c++

I have the following packet layout:

```
struct PacketLayout
{
  int GateCode;
  BYTE StringLen;
  char String[StringLen];
  BYTE ServerStatus;
  BYTE ServerStorage;
  BYTE ServerNumber;
}
```

The class is this:

```
class ServerInfo
{
  short PacketSize;   //Size of the whole packet
  BYTE TotalServers; //total of PacketLayout structs
  PacketLayout Server[TotalServers];
  int GlobalSecCode;
  short EncryptedPacketSize; //Same as the first member, just xored
}
```

So the problem i have is making an variable size array inside an class or an struct which size depends of the last member pointed by **BYTE StringLen** (for struct) and **BYTE TotalServers** (for the class).

I don't know what is the solution to this, maybe implement a template?, if that's so can i see an example (i am not familiar with templates yet) also i want to reference my member names without calculating the pointer position by myself (as i am currently doing now).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by: *"i want to reference my member names without calculating the pointer position by myself "*

Comment: There's no solution to this problem in standard C++. Templates are not going to help unless you know the value of ServerInfo.TotalServer and PacketLayout.StringLen  at compile time. You're just going to have to calculate the offsets yourself.

Comment: Flexo right now i am calculating the pointer position by myself to the string member since there is no way to make it a compile time.

Comment: Are you sure @jahhaj? i find this quiet disturbing... isnt a more high level approach beside calculating the offsets by myself like old ASM days? lol

Comment: @ffenix: I'm sure, unless of course you're prepared to resdesign your program. You've chosen a very low level approach, maybe you should try something more abstract?

Comment: @ffenix - you can use pointer to member syntax if you wanted to, but I'm fairly sure that's not what you want. There's also `offsetof` for computing offsets for you at compile time, but that seems to be the wrong solution to your problem too.

Comment: I wish i could redesign it, but i am recv the packets from a client wich is already compiled (yes its an emulator) so i am quiet forced to stick with all the packets layout present.

Comment: i edited the post, please look at the first and last members, if that makes any difference, thanks !

Comment: @jahhaj - just write a function that pulls the bytes in off the wire and puts them into the right place of a sensibly designed struct then. 1:1 mapping between packets and structs isn't always the way to go.

Comment: @Flexo: Yep, I agree with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this with a template is possible, for example:

```
template <int StringSize>
struct PacketLayout
{
  int GateCode;
  BYTE StringLen;
  char String[StringSize];
  BYTE ServerStatus;
  BYTE ServerStorage;
  BYTE ServerNumber;
};
```

lets you use this as:

```
PacketLayout<100> pkt;
```

Normally what you would want to do is simpler though. For example if you reorder the packet and know the upper limit on size you can do simply:

```
struct PacketLayout
{
  int GateCode;
  BYTE StringLen;
  BYTE ServerStatus;
  BYTE ServerStorage;
  BYTE ServerNumber;
  char String[MAX_POSSIBLE_SIZE];
};
```

Or alternatively:

```
struct PacketLayout
{
  int GateCode;
  BYTE StringLen;
  BYTE ServerStatus;
  BYTE ServerStorage;
  BYTE ServerNumber;
  char *String;
};
```

and allocate/set `String` during reading.

Personally though I'd skip all this messy low level details and use something like [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) to do the work for you and leave you free to concentrate on the more important higher level things that add value to your project.

There's a common but dirty trick used sometimes too:

```
struct PacketLayout
{
  int GateCode;
  BYTE StringLen;
  BYTE ServerStatus;
  BYTE ServerStorage;
  BYTE ServerNumber;
  char String[1];
};
```

Where people define the size of the variable part at the end to be 1 and then deliberately allocate more memory than needed for the struct so they can write past the end of it. This is evil and very much not recommended though.

Comment: What about the class? the class have also a variable array of PacketLayout structs, and i dont know the size of the PacketLayout in compile time. The size of the string is pointed by StringLen member.

Comment: @ffenix can you use an `std::string` instead of your `char` array?

Comment: @ffenix: This is your problem, unless you know these sizes at compile time templates are not going to help you. See how Flexo has written `PacketLayour<100> pkt;`, the 100 must be a compile time constant.

Comment: @juanchopanza - that doesn't seem to be an option here - it looks like this is something that's meant to be a POD, i.e. can be written to a file/stream directly.

Comment: @jahhaj: Mostly of the packets i recv on my server are undetermined size by compile time, so i am screw to analyze them in a reasonable high level syntax?

Comment: @ffenix - not screwed, but you've made your life hard with that layout. Normally you'd put the variable length bit at the end of the packet and stick a pointer to some dynamically allocated memory or just an array of the max size at the end.

Comment: I forget to mention that lol i have the packet size as last member of the class and as the beginning member of the class too.

Comment: I wonder how this is a solution to the problem, as it has been accepted, but clearly the size of the array is not dependent on the runtime value of `StringLen` which is what the question was about...

Answer (score 0):

Using templates is definitely the way to go:

```
template <size_t TotalServers>
class ServerInfo 
{
    PacketLayout Server[TotalServers];
    int GlobalSecCode;
};
```

This has the disadvantage of not having one `ServerInfo` assignable to another, so possibly using a `std::vector` is important, if that means a lot to you.

Comment: What about initializing the struct, its the same method? also as pointed on the answer by Flexo, i need to get the string sizes by the StringLen member, so can you set an more complete example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no nice way in C++ to achieve this.

This is how you can create variable size array in PacketLayout:

```
struct PacketLayout
{
  int GateCode;
  BYTE StringLen;
  BYTE ServerStatus;
  BYTE ServerStorage;
  BYTE ServerNumber;
  char String[1];
}
```

then you allocate an instance:

```
PacketLayout* createPacketLayout(BYTE stringLen)
{
    PacketLayout* packetLayout = (PacketLayout*)new char[sizeof(PacketLayout) - 1 + stringLen];
    packetLayout->StringLen = stringLen;
    return packetLayout;
}
```

in this case ServerInfo could hold array of pointers.